# bot framework v4 equivalent of Session.delay()?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm building a Microsoft Bot Framework v4 bot for SMS (Twillio channel, Node.js) and I need to control message delays, particularly when I'm sending images--otherwise things have a high probability of arriving to the user out of order.

In v3 bot framework, this could be easily achieved through using, for example, Session.delay(3000);

Is there an equivalent for v4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here's how I'm handling delays: in this scenario, I'm essentially adding an extra step to the waterfall that simply serves as a delay step after a HeroCard. Feels like there could be a better way?

```
const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Then, in the waterfall:

```
async thisIsAtextStep(step) {
            await step.context.sendActivity(
                `I am some text for the user`
            );
            return step.next();
        }

async thisIsAnimageStep(step) {
            const tocCard = CardFactory.heroCard(
                'This is an image',
                CardFactory.images([
                    'https://...someImage.png'
                ])
            );
            await step.context.sendActivity({
                attachments: [tocCard]
            });
            return step.next();
            }

 async addDelayStep(step) {
        console.log('timer start--let's wait');
        await timeout(13000);
        console.log('timer end--let's move to next step');
        return step.beginDialog(SOME_OTHER_DIALOG);
    }
```

Comment: Don't actually need that extra (step), though. It's enough just to insert the `await timeout(13000)` right before going to the next step/dialog...

Comment: Has your issue been resolved or do you still need help?

Comment: It's been solved, I can accept my answer tomorrow according to SO, unless there's a better way?

Comment: I think it's fine to wait until tomorrow

Comment: @Robbie thank you.  What does this work over a returned settimeout function?  Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did u try the following?

```js
await context.sendActivities([{ type: 'delay', value: 13000 }]);
```

Comment: Add some explanation for your code would be preferred.